# Why is using JScript for implementing custom actions in WiX not recommended?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

When browsing the documentation and discussions around WiX, espacially the sections about custom actions one can read that using JScript for implementing custom actions is not recommended.

But I haven't found a detailed explanation for these statements.

The background of the questions a requirement from a current project where the installer has to update some text file. This action is not available in the standard actions and the addons I found so far are all build against older versions of WiX. So it seems that I have to implement this custom action by myself.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx

Comment: @YanSklyarenko This was the reference I searched. Could you change your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rob Mensching](http://robmensching.com/) has [a great post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx) exactly about this topic. 
A summary of why it is a bad idea:

- Robust code is difficult write in script
- Debugging script in the Windows Installer is difficult
- Anti-virus products kill them

See details by the link above.